# Transform elements to <input> with "Edit" button and save data with "Save" button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="data"> 
    <li>Value 1</li>
    <li>Value 2</li>
    <li>Value 3</li>
    <li>Value 4</li>
</ul>

<br>

<div id="buttons">
<a id="edit">Click here to edit</a>
<br>
<a id="save">Click here to save</a>
</div>
```

I need to add an jQuery/Javascript snippet that transforms the `<li>` elements into `<input>` elements when the user clicks on the edit button, so he can write and change the values.

Once the process is done, with the save button the data backs to `li` with the values changed.

I have this jQuery code:

```
$('#edit').on('click',function() {
    $('#data').each(
        function(){
            if ($(this).find('input').length){
                $(this).text($(this).find('input').val());
            }
            else {
                var t = $(this).text();
                $(this).text('').append($('<input />',{'value' : t}).val(t));
            }
        });
});
```

But my idea is to separate this in two different buttons and I can't get it to work.

How can I do that? I know it shouldn't be difficult but the truth is I don't handle jQuery/Javascript very well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Comment: What is your effort to try this ?

Comment: I tried something like this http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/767y4/8/ and i tried to separate it in 2 different buttons but i cant get it to work correctly

Comment: `<li>` elements must be contained within an `<ol>` or `<ul>` element, so your original HTML is invalid. Also, you don't need to transform the `li` into `input` elements, you just need to add `contenteditible` attributes to the `li` elements to make them editable.

Comment: Thank you. Now i have the ```<li>``` elements contained into a  ```<ul>```. So you say that it's better to use ```contenteditable="true/false"``` property with the buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to convert the `li` elements to `inputs`, that needlessly complicates the process. You can just add the [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) attribute. You can still add input-handling events to these, they largely function like any other text based `input` element with that attribute enabled.

You can also change the button itself (both the inner text, and the function that fires when clicked in either state) instead of requiring two buttons.

```js
var data = document.getElementById('data'),
    btn  = document.getElementById('edit'),
    lis  = data.querySelectorAll('li');
    
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  lis.forEach(function(li){
    li.toggleAttribute('contenteditable');
  });
  
  if( lis[0].hasAttribute('contenteditable') ){
    // Currently editing, change the button
    btn.innerText = 'Click here to Save';
  } else {
    // We just "saved". run "save functions" here
    btn.innerText = 'Click here to Edit';
  }
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] { outline: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<ul id="data"> 
    <li>Value 1</li>
    <li>Value 2</li>
    <li>Value 3</li>
    <li>Value 4</li>
</ul>

<br>

<div id="buttons">
  <button id="edit">Click here to Edit</button>
</div>
```

If you do need two buttons, you can add a second button event handler, change `toggleAttribute` to `addAttribute` and `removeAttribute`, and remove the "inner text" changing code. But something like the above should be more than enough to get you started.

Also of note: `li` elements need to be inside a list container `ol` or `ul`, and `a` elements need an `href` attribute, so I've updated both of those to more semantically appropriate `ul` and `button` elements, respectively.

Comment: `forEach` in `NodeList` (querySelectorAll result), is pretty new. Support for Crome 55, Edge 16, FF 50, no IE!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: Thanks @Sysix, it's important to note support. That said, it could easily be changed to `(for var i=0, n = lis.length; i<n; i++){ lis[i].toggleAttribute('contenteditable'); }` or similar, I was trying to illustrate some working code that's still relatively easy to read, not write the most globally use-case containing functionality to be copy/pasted into production lol, hence the 'enough to get you started'. IE use is ~3% in the US and ~1% worldwide, safe to say assume that OP can modify to their needs as necessary 8-)

Comment: @Sysix The ability to use `Array.prototype.forEach()` on the node list returned by `.querySelectorAll()` isn't really that new. It's been supported for a few years now in all major browsers. And, if we're still concerned with IE, you'd use `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList).forEach(...)`, but honestly the use of IE at this point is really in edge cases and (finally) no longer the main stream.

Answer (score 1):

`<li>` elements must be contained within an `<ol>` or `<ul>` element, so your original HTML is invalid. Also, you don't need to transform the `li` into `input` elements, you just need to add `contenteditible` attributes to the `li` elements to make them editable.

Lastly, don't use `a` elements just as a `click` event hook. Any item can have a `click` event set up for it. `<a>` elements are for navigation.

```js
// Get reference to the list
const list = document.getElementById("data");

document.getElementById("edit").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  // Loop over the child elements
  list.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(li){
    // Make the element editable
    li.setAttribute("contenteditable","true");  
  });
});

document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  // Loop over the child elements
  list.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(li){
    // Make the element editable
    li.removeAttribute("contenteditable");  
  });
});
```

```css
#edit, #save { color:blue; cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<ul id="data"> 
    <li>Value 1</li>
    <li>Value 2</li>
    <li>Value 3</li>
    <li>Value 4</li>
</ul>

<br>

<div id="buttons">
<span id="edit">Click here to edit</span>
<br>
<span id="save">Click here to save</span>
</div>
```